# Google SignIn button Android ideal Right-to-Left ideal behavior

Tags: android, google-signin, android-button, right-to-left

**Background:**

If we set `android:supportsRtl=true` in `AndroidManifest.xml` for `<application` tag, then the app supports right-to-left (RTL) layouts. For Right-to-Left languages (or if you set `Force RTL layout direction` in developer options), the text / buttons appear as mirrored as follows throughout the device:

[image: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html]

*Source: [Google's blog on native RTL support](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)*

**Question:**

What's the expected behavior of Google's SignIn button? Should the logo be on the right instead of the left and the text move to left of the logo, instead of being on the right of the logo?

**What have I tried?**

- I read the [Sign-In Branding Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines) given by Google. It doesn't mention anything related to right-to-left scenario.
- I tried multiple apps with Google SignIn button on Android, including the [Google sample app for implementing SignIn button on Android](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin). They don't seems to follow it for the SignIn button. For the Google sample, it looks as follows in both left-to-right and right-to-left scenarios:

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to put layout_gravity with values of start and end